# Value for fisher exact test in R

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

I'm using `R` to calculate the Fisher Exact test on a contingency table.  I need it because in some table cells, I have values lower than 5, so I can't use `Chi-square`.

I use
`fisher.test(table)`,
but this only gives me a p-value.

---

Question:
What if I also need a value for the test statistic?

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I did exactly what @Ben did in his first answer, and got the same results. Nonetheless, SPSS also give me a valure for the FI(x) as explained here (p. 151) [link](http://www.csun.edu/sites/default/files/exact-tests20-32bit.pdf). How do I calculate this in R?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the last 5 years? @Forinstance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?  From a clean R session  (R-devel, but I would be very surprised if this were different in any recent version of R

```
z <- matrix(c(2,17,8,3),nrow=2)
(f <- fisher.test(z))
##
##  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
## data:  z
## p-value = 0.0009742
## alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
## 95 percent confidence interval:
##  0.003595195 0.413247726
## sample estimates:
## odds ratio 
## 0.05159674
```

This gives you the odds ratio. `f$estimate` extracts the value, if you want to use it in further computations.

Comment: Yes this is fine for 2x2 tables. But when I run the test in SPSS in a mxn table, I also got a value for the test statistic like in the picture: http://s28.postimg.org/69gucg371/Untitled_1.jpg. So, I was wondering why and how to calculate it in R.